# System timezone vs selected timezone

Tags: ios, timezone, nstimezone

> **What's the best way to compare two time zones?**

I'm facing an issue while comparing two `NSTimeZone` instances using `- (BOOL)isEqualToTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)aTimeZone` method.

```
NSString *timeZoneName = ...

NSTimeZone *sytemTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *selectedTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneName];

if ([sytemTimeZone isEqualToTimeZone:selectedTimeZone]) 
    isEqual = YES;  
else 
    isEqual = NO;
```

**Step 1:** Go to Settings (Application) > General > Date & Time > Time Zone and search for "Austin". The entry that you'll get will be "Austin, U.S.A". Select this Time Zone. This SHOULD be your new system time zone now!

**Step 2:** Create a small iPhone/iPad application. Use `[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]` to get a list of time zone names. Then try to find "Austin". It's not there! So, i guess we can use "America/Chicago" as the timezone?

> Why is the Setting's timezone list different from ours?

**Step 3:** Now compare the system timezone with time zone for "America/Chicago". They don't match.

Comment: If you log the system time zone's `name`, what does it show?

Comment: "US/Central (CDT) offset −18000 (Daylight)"

Comment: For "America/Chicago" set from with-in the application, it gives me "America/Chicago (CDT) offset −18000 (Daylight)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted a bug for this - The bug is that Austin isn't in the known time zone list yet is offered by the settings app.

As per an Apple Engineer:

> For two NSTimeZones to compare equal, both the names and the data (as
>   returns by -data) must be equal.  You have to be careful when
>   comparing time zones, because two zones can have the same offset from
>   GMT but not be the same time zone for historical reasons.  Remember
>   that time zones are used for all sorts of calendrical calculations,
>   meaning that they are only equal if, throughout history, they've
>   always had the same GMT offset, the same daylight savings transitions,
>   and so on.